# Convert image asset to base64 in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, base64, assets

How to convert an image on my assets folder to base64 using Flutter?

My pubspec.yaml

```
assets:
 - assets/sticker_packs.wasticker
 - assets/WAStickersPack/
```

`sticker_packs.wasticker` is a json map to all .png images under `assets/WAStickersPack/`

I get files so

```
for (var item in stickers) {
  var file = 'assets/WAStickersPack/' + item["image_file"];

  var img = AssetImage(file);
  //or
  var imgto = await rootBundle.load(file);
}
```

But i dont know how to convert to base64

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-convert/base64-constant.html but why would you want to do that? if you want to upload it to some remote host it will only make your data 33% bigger

Comment: I just want to use locally @pskink

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

ByteData bytes = await rootBundle.load('assets/images/logo_splash.png');
var buffer = bytes.buffer;
var m = base64.encode(Uint8List.view(buffer));
```

Comment: oh sorry forgot: 
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

Comment: After a long search I finally found solution for the problem I had with my app with your solution. Thanks

Answer (score -4):

```
_base64 = BASE64.encode(image);
```